# Alamofire not working after imported

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I am following along to a Udemy course, in which Alamofire is used for downloading data from an API to an Xcode Project.

However, after installing Alamofire, and importing it into my swift file, it isn't recognising anything to do with Alamofire (besides one thing: AlamofireVersionNumber).

I have the newest updates for Alamofire, Xcode and Cocoapods, and I just can't figure out what is wrong. Below I have put both my swift file, and an Alamofire example of what I am trying to achieve with my GET request.

Swift file:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class Pokemon {

fileprivate var _name: String!
fileprivate var _pokedexID: Int!
fileprivate var _description: String!
fileprivate var _type: String!
fileprivate var _defense: String!
fileprivate var _height: String!
fileprivate var _weight: String!
fileprivate var _attack: String!
fileprivate var _nextEvolutionTxt: String!
fileprivate var _nextEvolutionName: String!
fileprivate var _nextEvolutionId: String!
fileprivate var _nextEvolutionLevel: String!
fileprivate var _pokemonURL: String!

var name: String {

    return _name

}

var pokedexID: Int {

    return _pokedexID

}

init(name: String, pokedexID: Int) {

    self._name = name
    self._pokedexID = pokedexID

    self._pokemonURL = "\(URL_BASE)\(URL_POKEMON)\(self.pokedexID)/"

}

func downloadPokemonDetail(completed: DownloadComplete) {

    //This is where the GET request should be



}

}
```

The GET request example:

```
//Note that the issue is the word Alamofire that is not being recognised in my project

Alamofire.request(.GET, _pokemonURL).responseJSON { response in

    //Code for the response to go here

    print(response.result.value)

}
```

Edit:

I am using the .xcworkspace file, not the .xcodeproj, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: did you open workspace? do NOT open project

Comment: I did. I am opening it with the .xcworkspace file rather than the .xcodeproj.

Comment: so some windows style close and open or even restart, if that does not help install everything again step by step with instructions

Comment: I'll restart now and see if it sorts it

Comment: Fully shut down the mac and reopened the project, but still the same problem.

Comment: remove alamofire, start again step by step, you will be doing this so many times that you need to make it